# Run time error 217 at 00406786

Tags: delphi

> Delphi 2010:Run time error 217 at 00406786.

Не знаю, что за ошибка, собственно вот код:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var 
    Params:TStringList;
    InetParams:TStringList;

    i,k:Integer;
    inipath:string;
begin

{Settings section start}
inipath:=GetCurrentDir+'\services.ini';
 Settings:=TIniFile.Create(inipath);
  Params:= TStringList.Create;
  InetParams:=TStringList.Create;
  try
    Params.StrictDelimiter:= True;
    Params.CommaText:= Settings.ReadString('Telephone', 'catidx_values', '-1');
    TEL_SERV_COUNT:=Params.Count;
    SetLength(tel_serv, TEL_SERV_COUNT);
    i:=1;k:=1;
    while i<=TEL_SERV_COUNT do
    begin
      tel_serv[I] := Trim(Params[I-1]);
      inc(i);
    end;

    InetParams.CommaText:= Settings.ReadString('Internet', 'catidx_values', '-1');
    INET_SERV_COUNT:=InetParams.Count;
    SetLength(inet_serv, INET_SERV_COUNT);
   while k<=INET_SERV_COUNT do
   begin

     inet_serv[k]:= Trim(InetParams[k-1]);
     //ShowMessage(Inet_serv[i]);
    // ShowMessage(InetParams[k-1]);
    Inc(k);
    end;

  finally
    Params.Free;
    InetParams.Free;
    Settings.Free;
  end;

    {Settings section end}
end;
```

---

```
procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
//Application.Terminate;
end;
```

Уже все варианты закрытия программы попробовал, но все время показывает ран-тайм ошибку. Почему?
P.S: Интересно, что если комментировать строку во втором цикле

```
inet_serv[k]:= Trim(InetParams[k-1]);
```

то не будет ошибки вообще... Что может быть, плиз... Жду помощи и советов.

Comment: Странно, убрал в коде SetLength, а длину массивов ручную задал,и стало правильно работать..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как я понял из кода, tel_serv и inet_serv - это массивы типа array of string. если так, то в коде обращение к элементам этих массивов происходит по неправильным индексам. в динамических массивах используется zero-based индексация, в коде же используется 1-based. достаточно только заменить tel_serv[I] на tel_serv[I - 1] и inet_serv[k] на inet_serv[k - 1] и ошибка исчезнет.

Answer (score 0):

Да, [@maxionans](/users/4557/maxionans) прав, у вас неправильно идут обращения к элементам динамического массива. 
Почитайте раздел о списках, динамических массивах и как работает SetLength.
В вашем коде надо бы как-то так:

```
...
i := 0;
while i < TEL_SERV_COUNT do
begin
  tel_serv[i] := Trim(Params[i]);
  inc(i);
end;
...
k := 0;
while k < INET_SERV_COUNT do
begin
  inet_serv[k]:= Trim(InetParams[k]);
  Inc(k);
end;
...
```

Comment: Спасибо,всем,за ответы.Попробую как вы сказали.